# using add/remove program for python exe file

Tags: python

I build a exe file using pyinstaller.py let's say my source ode called test.py, I build test.exe, and write a installer call installtest.py which will build installtest.exe, same as Uninstalltest...both are work as I expected, able to install test.exe to right place and unstall it.

my question is how can I write a key able to using using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall..
then able to add/remove program to uninstall it .

Thanks

Comment: any examples will be greatly appreciated

Comment: AFAIK PyInstaller creates standalone executables which are portable. Aren't you supposed to use a system installer program that deals with those aspects, like Inno Setup or so ?

Comment: thanks, I am using PyInstaller create standalone  executables, just wish to uninstall it using add/remove programs like all the instalations.